# How to pass php variable value returned by javascript to a php variable?

Tags: javascript, php

HTML (When this DIV is clicked a call to searchfunction made and its id is passed)

```
<div class="me" id="<?php echo $row['main_cat_id'];?>" onClick="searchfunction('<?php echo $row['main_cat_id'];?>');">
    <?php echo $row[ 'main_cat_name'];?>
</div>
```

Below is the search function; it passes the ID value of the clicked DIV to the page`getparam.php`.

```
 function searchfunction(param) {
    //alert(param);
    var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            if (this.responseText !== null) {
                var ajaxElm = document.getElementById('getparam');
                ajaxElm.innerHTML = this.responseText; // append in front
                //jQuery(ajaxElm).append(this.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getparam.php?param=" + param, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And `getparam.php` only passes back the ID to the same page it got it from. I've resorted to this method, because I believe there's no way to directly pass the id of the clicked div which was captured by JavaScript and assign it to a php variable.

```
<?php
$param=$_GET['param'];
echo $param;
?>
```

Now, I need the value of clicked div id to run this query below:

echo `$param='<span id="getparam"></span>';`//it does echo the id in numeric like, 1 or 2 .But it doesn't help to execute the query though.

```
 $sql= "SELECT * FROM categories,main_category WHERE categories.main_cat_id=main_category.main_cat_id AND categories.main_cat_id='$param'";
```

How can I get the clicked DIV id passed to the php variable `$param`? Is there any other way or can anything be improved here?

Comment: I looked at that code for several minutes and i still have no idea what you are doing. Why don't you simply put the query into a file, redirect the AJAX to it and then just `$sql = "SELECT * ... AND categories.main_cat_id='".$param."'";`?

Answer (score 2):

`Javascript` is client side and `PHP` has the server side. You can store the value of a php variable to a variable of `JAVASCRIPT` but you can't do the reverse.

In order to save the value of `javascript`, you would need to make an ajax call to the server side to store the value in `php`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't unstand you very clearly. Do you prepare to get the `js` function `searchfunction(param)` into your SQL sentence in PHP code?
if so you may just try `$sql= "SELECT * FROM categories,main_category WHERE categories.main_cat_id=main_category.main_cat_id AND categories.main_cat_id='{$param}'";`

Comment: so where `$param='<span id="getparam"></span>';` shows? can you show your whole code or tell me your purpose?

Comment: I already placed the code above.  The problem now is, $param='<span id="getparam"></span>'; is not echoing inside the query. When I simply echo $param='<span id="getparam"></span>'; it does show the ID of clicked item. I expect the veluw to be reflected inside the query too but it doesnt

Comment: Now the most important is that I can't understand that is there any relationship between the first 2/3 part before `$param='<span id="getparam"></span>';` and the rest. You just create a HTML DOM, and you want get the div's id as a query param in SQL? if so which file the SQL sentence located in?